# Return value by two copies

Tags: c++, gcc

I am analyzing the returning value by function. See below for the actual question:

```
struct S{ int a, b, c, d;  };
S f(){
 S s;
 s.b=5;
 return s;
}

int main(){
  S s= f(); 
  s.a =2;
}
```

compiler output from [`gcc 5.3 -O0 -fno-elide-constructors` on godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%2C%22colouriseAsm%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A[%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22M4FwTgrgxiAEDKBvAULNBLAdnAhgblQ21gCMC1Ys4pyi4ATA5AXwPlgDMAKAShQVjBywAHQkAvAFZyYAKYgIYTIILNkyKrAC2OLL34Dg4zrzyxConLHEAmJsyAA%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22g530%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-O0%20-fno-elide-constructors%22%7D]%7D):

```
f():
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movl    $5, -28(%rbp)
        leaq    -32(%rbp), %rdx
        leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rdx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    S::S(S const&)
        movq    -16(%rbp), %rax
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
        leave
        ret
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $32, %rsp
        call    f()
        movq    %rax, -16(%rbp)
        movq    %rdx, -8(%rbp)
        leaq    -16(%rbp), %rdx
        leaq    -32(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rdx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        call    S::S(S const&)
        movl    $2, -32(%rbp)
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
```

What is my problem?

1. Why there are called two copy constructors? I don't understand why it is needful.

Comment: Nononono, the code is better than a link. BTW, this link looks _crazy_ and is formatted as code so no one will probably visit it

Comment: If you do not want to post the full code here that is fine. But at least post a minimal version that has the problem you describe

Comment: not really interested in clicking sketchy links in the first place.

Comment: The link is relevant because it contains the disassembly of OP's program, which shows instructions for two copy constructor calls.

Comment: Returning from a function involves a copy. Creation of a local variable involves another copy.

Comment: @ForceBru - what's wrong with godbolt links? [(see this related meta-question)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319549/how-are-we-supposed-to-post-godbolt-links-now-that-url-shortening-is-blocked)

Comment: @Chris, yep, I've stumbled upon this question several minutes after commenting here.

Comment: @Chris If you take a look at the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36205215/timeline), you'll see that all those comments came before Simple imported the code from the link-shortener. And most comment only/mostly focus on not having that code here.

Comment: @Deduplicator: There was never a link-shortener involved, just the full ~1k character godbolt.org link that encodes the full source code and compiler options into the URL.  But yes, you should always post at least a snippet of the code and the asm you're talking about, with a godbolt link for people to easily try it with different compile options or a modification to the source.  And obviously the link should be posted as a link, with a description that might make sense to people who don't know about http://gcc.godbolt.org/.  **Agreed this was a horrible question until the edit.**

Comment: @PeterCordes Seems I should have looked into the small-print a bit longer too... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy constructor inside `f()` is called, because a "return" with the object is used. This prompts it to create a copy of it into a temporary variable and then this gets passed to the `main`.  Copy constructor inside main is obvious `f()` returns an `S` object, and it gets copied to "`s`"

Answer (score 2):

One of the two times the constructor is called to build a temporary object used as return value of `f()`. If you want to avoid this additional overhead, you have to rely on [C++11 move constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor).

Comment: When is built temporary object ( please give me number of lines)

Comment: @Gilgamesz:  In this case, you should just compile with any level of optimization (even the minimal `-Og` optimize for debugging, and `f()` will compile to `movabsq $21474836480, %rax` / `movl    $0, %edx` / `ret`.  `main()` of course optimizes away entirely.)